# бот задваивает сообщения

Tags: telegram-bot, google-spreadsheet

Есть бот учета рабочего времени написан на GAS - две кнопки - начать смену и закончить смену, время записывается в таблицу, юзеру прилетает сообщение что смена окончена - с началом смены все хорошо, а вот окончание непрогнозируемо задваивается по 10-20+ раз, причем задваивает не всегда и не у всех пользователей, в таблице соответственно тоже несколько однотипных записей
запись вида: сотрудник время начала 01.01.1970 04:00:00 время окончания 04.08.2023 18:15:20
т.е как бы не находит запись в таблице с началом смены, но иногда сообщения приходят и с правильным временем начала смены из таблицы

про ограничения gas в курсе, с ботом работают 20 человек, бота писал не я, достался в наследство в новой орг

вот функция отправки сообщения

```
const ST_endShift = makeAction( //стартовая страница
  user => user.perm1lvl == '☑️' && user.message === KB_EndShift[0][0].text,
  user => {
    fixShift(user, 'stop')
  })
```

```
function fixShift(user, status) {
  switch (status) {
    case 'start':
      if (true) {
        sendMessage_Keyboard(user.id, MSG_StartShift, KB_EndShift)
        const worker = user.fio ? user.fio : user.id
        const dataToComing = [new Date(), user.id, worker, user.perm1lvl, 'Начало смены']
        const sheetComing = user.ss.getSheetByName(SHT_COMING)

        Utilities.sleep(getRandomIntInclusive(1, 40) * 250)
        // sheetComing.getRange(sheetComing.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, dataToComing.length).setValues([dataToComing])
        sheetComing.appendRow(dataToComing)
        SpreadsheetApp.flush()
        sheetComing.getRange(`2:2`).copyTo(sheetComing.getRange(`3:${sheetComing.getLastRow()}`), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false)
      }
      break;

    case 'stop':
      if (true) {
        const sheetComing = user.ss.getSheetByName(SHT_COMING)
        const sheetWork = user.ss.getSheetByName(SHT_WORKTIME)
        const dataComing = sheetComing.getDataRange().getValues().filter(row => row[1].toString() === user.id && row[4] === 'Начало смены')
        const dataStartShift = dataComing[dataComing.length - 1]

        const worker = user.fio ? user.fio : user.id
        const timeValueStart = new Date(dataStartShift[0])
        const now = new Date()

        const dataToComing = [now, user.id, worker, user.perm1lvl, 'Конец смены']
        const dataToWork = [ddMMyyyy(now), user.id, worker, timeValueStart, now]

        sendMessage_Keyboard(user.id, MSG_EndShift, KB_StartShift)

        const timestamp = Math.floor((now.getTime() - timeValueStart.getTime()) / 1000)
        const hours = (Math.floor(timestamp / 60 / 60)).toString().padStart(2, '0')
        const minutes = (Math.floor(timestamp / 60) - (hours * 60)).toString().padStart(2, '0')
        const seconds = (timestamp % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')
        sendMessage(user.id, MSG_report(ddMMyyyyHHmm(timeValueStart), ddMMyyyyHHmm(now), [hours, minutes, seconds].join(':')))


        Utilities.sleep(getRandomIntInclusive(10, 40) * 250)
        sheetComing.appendRow(dataToComing)
        sheetWork.appendRow(dataToWork)
        SpreadsheetApp.flush()
        sheetComing.getRange(`2:2`).copyTo(sheetComing.getRange(`3:${sheetComing.getLastRow()}`), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false)
        sheetWork.getRange(`2:2`).copyTo(sheetWork.getRange(`3:${sheetWork.getLastRow()}`), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false)
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

do post

```
function doPost(e) {
  const contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)
  let user = {
    contents: contents,
    ss: SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS_BOT),
  }
  // debug(user, contents)

  if (contents.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
    user.id = String(contents.message.from.id)
    user.name = contents.message.from.first_name
    user.nickName = contents.message.from.username
    user.chat = String(contents.message.chat.id)
    user.message = contents.message.text
    user = checkUserPermissions(user, contents)

    main(user)

  } else if (contents.hasOwnProperty('callback_query')) {
    user.message = contents.callback_query.data
    if (user.message == 'null') { return }

    user.id = String(contents.callback_query.from.id)
    user.name = contents.callback_query.from.first_name
    user.nickName = contents.callback_query.from.username
    user.chat = String(contents.callback_query.message.chat.id)
    user = checkUserPermissions(user, contents)

    if (/permissionLevel/.test(user.message) && (user.id === ADMIN)) {
      try { adminSetPermissionLevel(user) } catch (e) { Logger.log(e) }
    } else {
      main(user)
    }

  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  return 0
}
```

функция main

```
function main(user) {
  const currentState = getProperty(user.id, 'state', 'start')
  const actions = states[currentState]
  for (let i in actions) {
    sendChatAction(user.id, 'typing')
    try {
      if (actions[i].condition(user)) {
        actions[i].action(user)
        return 0
      }
    } catch (e) { sendMessage(user.chat, [e, e.name, e.message]) }
  }
  setProperty(user.id, 'state', currentState)
  return sendMessage(user.chat, MSG_errorInBot)
}
function getProperty(id = '', property = 'state', defaultValue) {
  let userProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  return userProperties.getProperty(`${property}_${id}`) || defaultValue;
}
```